# Dataproc arguments not being read on spark submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-submit

I am using dataproc to submit jobs on spark.  However on spark-submit, non-spark arguments are being read as **spark arguments!**

I am receiving the error/warning below when running a particular job.

`Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false`

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster my-cluster \
--region us-east1 \
--properties dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false,spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=$SPARK_CONF,spark.executor.memory=${MEMORY}G,spark.executor.cores=$total_cores \
--class com.sample.run \
--jars gs://jars/jobs.jar \
-- 1000
```

I would like to know whats wrong with my current format.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`spark-submit` just silently ignored conf options that did not start with spark.
thats the reason for this property it was saying it was ignored.

```
--properties dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false
```

any property you should pass as `spark.`propertyname

this is just warning.

Why this property required :

> The Conscrypt security provider has been temporarily changed from the
>   default to an optional security provider. This change was made due to
>   incompatibilities with some workloads. The Conscrypt provider will be
>   re-enabled as the default with the release of Cloud Dataproc 1.2 in
>   the future. In the meantime, you can re-enable the Conscrypt provider
>   when creating a cluster by specifying this Cloud Dataproc property:

`--properties` `dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=true`
This has to be specified when creating cluster since this is cluster property, not property of spark. (means spark framework cant able to understand this and simply ignored.)

Example usage :

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create my-test
--project my-project
--subnet prod-sub-1
--zone southamerica-east1-a
--region=southamerica-east1
--master-machine-type n1-standard-4
--master-boot-disk-size 40
--num-workers 5
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-4
--worker-boot-disk-size 20
--image-version 1.2
--tags internal,ssh,http-server,https-server
--properties dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false
--format=json
--max-idle=10m
```

and then start job like this...

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://path-to-script/spark_full_job.py
--cluster=my-test
--project=my-project
--region=southamerica-east1
--jars=gs://path-to-driver/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar
--format=json -- [JOB_ARGS]
```